# Creating a rails 3 generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a rails generator:

```
class TaggableGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  hook_for :orm, :as => "model"
end
```

Everything works fine, but I would like to set the fields created in the models and create multiple models, I can't find anything about how to do it (I got the above code from looking at the devise generators) preferably I'd like it to me orm generic (but its not that important).

Comment: Did you look at the generators in the nifty-generators gem?

Comment: yes, but I still can't get my head around it

Answer (score 1):

Here is some links that may help you:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/218-making-generators-in-rails-3
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Basically you just need to add methods in your class to do things you want (all the public methods will get called when the generator is called), here is an example from rails sources:

```
class AssetsGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)

  def copy_stylesheet
    copy_file "stylesheet.css", File.join('app/assets/stylesheets', class_path, "#{file_name}.css")
  end
end
```

the copy_file comes from Thor, you wan see a list of availables methods in the Thor reference: http://textmate.rubyforge.org/thor/Thor/Actions.html